# Change textarea font color based on text. Both on page load, and after content changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what I have
`<textarea onblur="this.value='Enter a new task...')?'#A7A7A7':'initial'" rows="4" cols="50" id="position'.$i.'" class="taskbox">'.$task.'</textarea>`

That's not working for me. It's wrong anyway. I'm using jquery. Basically if the field is blank or equals 'Enter a new task...' then I want the font color to be #A7A7A7, otherwise leave it the default color.

This needs to happen on initial page load, aswell as onblur. When it's onfocus, the color should always be initial.

EDIT this is trimmed down from some PHP, so you'll notice PHP code in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/eVRQD/

HTML

```
<textarea id="mytxt" rows="4" cols="50">Enter a new task...</textarea>
```

JS

```
determineColor();

$('#mytxt').blur(function() {
  determineColor();
});

function determineColor(){
    var mytxtval = $('#mytxt').val();
    if( mytxtval === 'Enter a new task...' || mytxtval === '' ){
        $('#mytxt').css('color', 'red');
    } else {
         $('#mytxt').css('color', 'green');
    }
}
```

Comment: Going to test and tweak now.

Comment: Works, but the problem I'm having is that I'm using the identifier of textarea, not a specific class. I want this to style only the specific textarea with that value. I'm still tweaking it, but if you have a solution, I'm all ears.

Comment: I've accepted your answer as the solution. It didn't fix my problem, but that's because I left out the crucial detail that it was on a per textbox basis.

Comment: I switched the example code above to use an ID instead of a class, hope that helps.